# Checkout page: The requested qty is not available

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Wired issue **[Magento 2.3.2-p2]** While placing a final payment I'm getting
**"server 500 error The requested qty is not available"** While product qty is available.
If qty is not available then it should give error while adding to the cart not on the checkout page.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The requested qty is not available

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The requested qty is not available
<pre>#1 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote->updateItem(1049, &Magento\Framework\DataObject#00000000438f730900000000335e9cbe#) called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/CartItemPersister.php:73]
#2 Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\CartItemPersister->save(&Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor#00000000438f685400000000335e9cbe#, &Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Interceptor#00000000438f686800000000335e9cbe#) called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository/SaveHandler.php:82]
```

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 2):

i faced similar issue for configurable product,
you can check this file in vendor:

```
vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Quote/Item/CartItemProcessor.php:70
```

update this code: $requestData = ['id' => $cartItem->getItemId()];
[image]

if this code can fix your issue, you can create plugin to set cart item id to $requestData

seem this is bug from magento, they not set cart item id to buyRequest, but they checked it when init cart item by buyRequest:

```
vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/Processor.php:94
```

this issue happen when try save quote with configurable product.

Comment: I did the same which you suggested but not working .

Comment: For me too: Nothing has changed.. BUT:

RUN
`php bin/magento cache:clean`
`php bin/magento cache:flush`
`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`